# How do I get the host url in mail template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I have a mailer template in rails. I am trying to use the url of a paperclip attachment: `<%=item.picture.url%>`

OFcourse, this only renders the path which is pretty useless in an email. I need to get the absolute url.

Also since I am using `rake` to run the task, there is no request per se.
I remember setting the default host in
 `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'sitename.com' }`

How do I access this  value in the mailer template?

Comment: you can use `helper` in `actionmailer` and absolute url helper is `root_url`.

Comment: that did the trick. Why don't you make this an aswer so I can accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `helper` in `action-mailer` and absolute url helper is `root_url`.

Comment: I.e. just do this: `<%= root_url[0...-1] %><%= item.picture.url %>`

Answer (score -3):

Try this

You can get the host name using the below line of code

> request.host

Comment: there's no "request" when you're using rake to run a task.